# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Entity cannot be cast to com.example.Entity

Tags: java, jpa, classcastexception

I'm creating a JSF+JPA project for and GlassFish 4. A couple of times I get an exception at the at this point:

```
List<User> users = connection.getUserList();

for (User u : users) { //exception
```

...

```
    public List<User> getUserList() {

    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("project").createEntityManager();
    List<User> users = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM User c", User.class).getResultList();
    em.close();
    return users;
}
```

stacktrace:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: de.sep.ateam.sap.norris.model.User cannot be cast to de.sep.ateam.sap.norris.model.User
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: de.sep.ateam.sap.norris.model.User cannot be cast to de.sep.ateam.sap.norris.model.User
    at de.sep.ateam.sap.norris.controller.beans.LoginBean.doLogin(LoginBean.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Please, show your Exceptions stack trace.

Comment: @Rakesh: library/framework/product names like "JSF" and "GlassFish" are **not** code. Please stop formatting them as code in suggested edits.

Comment: Try for(Object u: users) { User user = (User) u; .....

Comment: Your entity classes are deployed twice. Check you .jar files!

Comment: So you get it on production? So you can't reproduce it every time?

Comment: sometimes when i deploy it everything works fine

Comment: I've faced this problem before, it happens because of some left overs from the old EntityManagerFactory, somehow its classloaders survived after redeployment, what you need to do is to close the factory just before you redeploy your app, you can use ServletContextListeners for that, it allows you to do exactly what you need, here is a tutorial on how to implement it: http://4dev.tech/2015/08/example-of-servletcontextlistener-implementation/

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that you don`t have multiple versions of the same class loaded in the application server, you might try to reset the server cache.

Follow this steps:

1. Undeploy the application;
2. Stop the application server;
3. Delete the osgi cache folder of your application server. I.e. if you are
   using glassfish, it is the folder:
   E:\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache
4. Restart the server;
5. Deploy the application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I finally found a workaround on java.net :

Copy all `org.eclipse.persistence jar files` from `glassfish4/glassfish/modules` to `WEB-INF/lib`.
Then go in your glassfish-web.xml, and set `class-delegate` to `false`.

Worked for me !

Comment: In my case it was sufficient to only add org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar and org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar to WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem  because I was serializing classes and the serialized versions couldn't be deserialized after the classes updated and the app was restarted without restarting the container.

Comment: how did you fix it? i'm serializing the classes too

Comment: We used things like `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` and updated the uid when we knew it would break deserialization and also sometimes just destroyed the cache on purpose.  Also, we have multiple caching strategies, but one of them was being run by the container (Tomcat) which we turned off on dev instances (where we update the apps without restarting the container) and have a container restart policy on deploy for production.  Oh, also sometimes the container when its rebooting an app has a hard to replacing classes because it can't unload some class on redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens when there is more than one instance of the same jar in a different class loader.  Most app servers have a global class loader and a web-app specific class loader (some also have others like contrib, etc.).  If the class loader that is higher up in the food chain has that class defined already and it gets redefined by a lower level class loader this sort of situation can occur (the same class in a different class loader is considered different even though its definition is the same).  The order of how/when jars get loaded is not guaranteed which could explain why you sometimes see the error and sometimes don't.  Long story short, make sure you haven't already deployed the jar that contains this class somewhere else in the server that is visible to your web app.